# Access a file outside the server directory

Tags: php, debian, root

I'm trying to use [this](https://github.com/ReduxRedstone/php-nbt-encoder-decoder) class to access a .dat file outside the root directory.

> $nbt->loadFile('/root/mc/servers/spigot-test/world/playerdata/faa2f0d7-c339-436b-b212-ae32ababaa41.dat');

But I'm getting an error that's triggered by an else statement on a is_file($filaname) (Line 44 of the class)

I tried adding the document root on the path but nothing works (Also given 777 perms to www-data on that file)

Could anybody help me?

**Edit** That was working until I reinstalled my VPS so I supose I done some cmd magic on that I don't remember

Answer (score 0):

If you say you can't access the file, because it is outside of your root directory, you could simply create a softlink to that file

```
ln -s /root/mc/servers/spigot-test/world/playerdata/faa2f0d7-c339-436b-b212-ae32ababaa41.dat /path/to/softlink
```

The softlink should be placed on a directory you can access. Then you load the file by refering to the softlink

```
$nbt->loadFile('/path/to/softlink');
```

Comment: I'd like to just give permission for www-data but I can't get it to work